# Deborphan Returning Non-Existent Package - Bug?

Tags: debian, deb, bug

Running version 1.7.28.8 of **deborphan**. It seems to think there is a package named `deb` installed. I've never heard of such a Debian package!

`deborphan -a | grep deb` returns:
`main/python  deb`
and `dpkg --get-selections "*" | awk '{ print $1 }' | awk -F : '{ print $1 }' | grep ^deb$` returns:
nothing...

In addition, `deborphan -a -d -P -s -z` returns:

```
      .
      .
      .
python-ecdsa (main/python - optional, 169)   
      deb
cpio (main/utils - important, 853)
      .
      .
      .
python-crypto (main/python - optional, 1276)
      bitpim
      deb
libopenjp2-7 (main/libs - extra, 314)
      .
      .
      . 
deb (main/python - optional, 614)
libgtksourceview2.0-common (main/libs - optional, 3079)
      .
      .
      .
python (main/python - standard, 680)
      hplip
      .
      .
      .
      python-six
      deb
      bitpim-lib
      .
      .
      .
      python-talloc
libjgoodies-common-java (main/java - optional, 90)
      .
      .
      .
```

Trying to track this down, but, as you might imagine, Google has not been too helpful.

How can I figure out what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume You're on Jessie (since newer distributions does not seem to include `bitpim` anymore).

It is highly likely the `deborphan`'s bug and the package that triggers it is `python-paramiko`.

This package has uncommon `Package-Type` tag in its control section:

```
$ apt-cache show python-paramiko | grep -i ^package
Package: python-paramiko
Package-Type: deb
```

and I think that `deborphan` just wrongly interprets this field as a package name.

Just as a side note: `debfoster` does not exhibit the same behavior (i.e. `debfoster -a | tr " " "\n" | grep ^deb$` is empty).

It is a pity, but I can not comment if it is fixed in more recent versions of `deborphan`, since `python-paramiko` package does not contain the tag `Package-Type` anymore.

Comment: Perhaps someone else who is using a newer version of Debian than is Jessie can provide some enlightenment...

Comment: I do :) I'm on mix of testing/sid/experimental actually, I've just got a virtual machine with Jessy, so I've had a possibility to test in original environment. However, newer version of `pyton-paramiko`, (`python3-paramiko` to be more precise, since python2 is gone now) is packaged differently, so I can not say definitely if the bug does remain but is not triggered or it is fixed. So newer Debian version is of no help there, sorry. It is better to ping the `deborpan` developers directly, if You are interested.

Comment: I can report that, under **Debian Stretch**, the subject problem no longer exists. Indeed, `apt-cache show python-paramiko | grep -i ^package` now yields merely `Package: python-paramiko`!